# Thread sleeping in a web page - but without the Thread class

Tags: asp.net

I need to have a web page wait for a few seconds before doing something. Let's say that for "security" reasons I can't use the `Thread` class, so I can't call its `Sleep` method (*don't ask*).

I McGyvered this solution:

```
DateTime foo = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);

while (DateTime.Now < foo) {
    /*noop*/
}
```

It did work in a Console application, and in a simple page I did just now. I have half a heart to use this but something lodged the darkest corners of my shadow self keeps telling me I am only paving the way to my own doom by doing this. I feel there is a catch to it, but I can't tell what it is.

Is it safe to use? Is it sane?

Comment: Delaying server-side processing is not a good idea in any case, but since you already decided to do it - this is as good method as any loop delays.

Comment: It is safe to use, however this method will waste CPU time spinning the empty loop (and Thread.Sleep will not). And I agree with Yuriy, request is not a right place to do such things.

Comment: Why can't you call the Sleep method? Odd.

Comment: I hope you're aware that you'll be holding up a worker thread for the duration of the sleep. That thread will not be available for processing other requests, and you'll be more likely to force requests to wait for worker threads.

Comment: Your instinct is strong, young one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mutex m = new Mutex();
w.WaitOne();
m.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

This is a hack of course. But your requirement is to not use `Thread.Sleep`.

Alternatively, call a web service that sleeps for 5 seconds. That way you at least don't burn CPU in your busy loop.

Comment: Wouldn't the first call to WaitOne block the thread, keeping me from ever reaching the second one?

Comment: The Mutex starts out untaken. The first call takes it. The 2nd waits.

Comment: Nice way to wait patiently.  The while loop feels like the kid in the back seat asking "are we there yet".    I've used similar waits on events.

Comment: I think it is a hack and I see no reason by thread sleep would be disallowed and this one allowed. Maybe bureaucracy?!